# How to have MediaElement player inside fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, mediaelement.js

HTML:

```
{% for movie in videos %}
    <div class="list_item">            
        <a class="open-fancybox" href="#fancybox">Play</a>
        <div id="fancybox">
          <video id="#mediaelement" src="{{ movie.file }}" preload=none></video>
        </div>      
    </div>   
{% endfor %}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           

        $('.open-fancybox').fancybox({
            'afterShow': function() {
                $('#mediaelement').mediaelementplayer();
            }
        });

});
```

There are no errors in firebug. The problem is that fancybox has the entire page as content but not the video.

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: @JFK If you like to share this as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to load the video dynamically instead of embedding it inline so I would do :

```
<a title="video title" data-poster="images/thumb.jpg" href="videos/video.mp4" class="fancy_video"><img alt="" src="images/thumb.jpg" /></a>
```

**Notice** we are linking to the (mp4) video directly within the `href` attribute. Also notice the (HTML5) `data-poster` attribute, which indicates the thumbnail image that will be displayed inside the video container when it is idle. Then the basic jQuery code :

```
// set some general variables
var $video_player, _player, _isPlaying = false;
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    jQuery(".fancy_video").fancybox({
        // set type of content (we are building the HTML5 <video> tag as content)
        type: "html",
        // other API options
        scrolling: "no",
        fitToView: false,
        autoSize: false,
        beforeLoad: function () {
            // build the HTML5 video structure for fancyBox content with specific parameters
            this.content = "<video id='video_player' src='" + this.href + "' poster='" + $(this.element).data("poster") + "' width='360' height='360' controls='controls' preload='none' ></video>";
            // set fancyBox dimensions
            this.width = 360; // same as video width attribute
            this.height = 360; // same as video height attribute
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            // initialize MEJS player
            var $video_player = new MediaElementPlayer('#video_player', {
                defaultVideoWidth: this.width,
                defaultVideoHeight: this.height,
                success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
                    _player = mediaElement; // override the "mediaElement" instance to be used outside the success setting
                    _player.load(); // fixes webkit firing any method before player is ready
                    _player.play(); // autoplay video (optional)
                    _player.addEventListener('playing', function () {
                        _isPlaying = true;
                    }, false);
                } // success
            });
        },
        beforeClose: function () {
            // if video is playing and we close fancyBox
            // safely remove Flash objects in IE
            if (_isPlaying && navigator.userAgent.match(/msie [6-8]/i)) {
                // video is playing AND we are using IE
                _player.remove(); // remove player instance for IE
                _isPlaying = false; // reinitialize flag
            };
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6z5ZB/)**

**NOTES** :

- Although the jsfiddle uses mediaelement.js v2.13.2 (the latest available at cdnjs) I would always recommend to update to the latest version (v2.14.2 so far) that includes bug fixes.
- The demo also uses fancyBox v2.1.15 and covers mp4 video files only.

For a full detailed code explanation, including known issues and workarounds you could refer to this tutorial http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/

Answer (score 2):

Hi I think you should remove the hash out of the id value:

`<div id="fancybox">` instead of `<div id="#fancybox">`

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to do something like this using the mediaelement wordpress plugin. I ended up with something like:

```
$('a.fancybox').fancybox({
    'afterShow': function() {
        mejs.$('video').mediaelementplayer();
    }
});
```